# Setting the value of a sandbox web part's custom properties in .webpart file

Tags: web-part, deployment, sandbox-solution, custom-web-part-property, web-part-property

I've created a new web part in a sandbox solution. This web part has a custom string property called 'PetName'.

I'd expect to be able to set the initial value of this property in the .webpart file. While this works perfectly in a Farm solution, in a Sandbox solution it does not. The field shows in the web part properties on the UI, but it is blank. I am able to persist a value if I enter a value into the field and click OK.

Does anyone have any idea how to manage this? I'm stumped.

Thanks,
Dave

DumbWebPart.cs:

```
namespace MyDumbWebPart.DumbWebPart
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class DumbWebPart : WebPart
    {
        [WebBrowsable(true), Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
        public string PetName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

DumbWebPart.webpart

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="MyDumbWebPart.DumbWebPart.DumbWebPart, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" />
      <importErrorMessage>$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="Title" type="string">MyDumbWebPart - DumbWebPart</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">My Web Part</property>
        <property name="PetName" type="string">Fluffy</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use get;set; as shown below sample:

```
private static string OverLayText="<b>This is an html</b>";
        [Category("Extended Settings"),
        Personalizable(),
        WebBrowsable(),
        WebDisplayName("OverLay text"),
        WebDescription("OverLay Text")]
        public string _OverLayText
        {
            get
            {
                return OverLayText;
            }
            set
            {
                OverLayText = value;
            }    
        }
```